# Adding function to Genesis genesis_header

Tags: php, plugin-development, hooks, actions, genesis-theme-framework

I am using a modified version of the Sample Genesis starter child theme by Sridhar Katakam (https://github.com/srikat/genesis-sample). I am trying to add a simple `div` by adding a function in the `genesis_header` hook.

```
// Add header bottom border
add_action('genesis_header', 'header_border_bottom', 14);
function header_border_bottom() { ?>
    <div id="HeaderBottomBorder"></div>
<?php }
```

(The priority of 14 was used since I saw in 'genesis\lib\structure\header.php' that the closing tags for the header were created by `add_action( 'genesis_header', 'genesis_header_markup_close', 15 );`)

This code is located in a "Must-Use" plugin I've created for this purpose. All code of this nature is wrapped in the following:

```
function framework_header_adjust() {
...
}
add_action('after_setup_theme','framework_header_adjust', 1, 1);
```

The code is not working. It did work for a previous function hooked to `genesis_site_title`. During the course of my research, I have seen people talk about replacing the header with a custom one. I do not want to do so if I do not need to, since I want the functionality it offers and only want to make stylistic and minor structural changes. I would rather use actions for this than filters.

Thank you so much.

Comment: It's not a mismatch of the number of arguments is it? Your function has none but your action hook says it expects one.

Comment: That worked! I cant believe I didn't consider that. Thank you

Comment: Cool. Wasn't able to test it myself but I've added it as an answer now. By all means accept it if you think it solved things for you :-)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a mismatch of the number of arguments. Your function has none but your action hook says it expects one.